# forRoot in Angular libraries not workig , but in appmodule its working as expected

Tags: dependency-injection, angular8, angular-cli-v8

When i import a module in appmodule and call forRoot everything is working no Injection problems.
But when i remove from appmodule and add in a lazyloaded module calling forRoot not working as expected.
Getting   **NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken forRoot()** , is it mandatory that all modules needs to be imported in appmodule. My main moto is to reduce the main.js bundle size , so don't want to load all modules in appmodule

Appmodule => featureModule.forRoot(env) => working Fine

LazyloadedModule => fetaureModule.forRoot(env) => Null Injector error

Answer (score 0):

Include your routes with RouterModule’s forChild method instead of forRoot

Reference : https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Issue is not related to router, lazyloading is working fine am able to go the lazyloaded module , but in lazyloaded module adding forRoot to pass environment variable to another feature module is not working. But works the same in appmodule adding feature module directly

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetaureModule.forChild(env)` instead of `fetaureModule.forRoot(env)`.

For all the lazy-loaded modules, we are supposed to use `forChild()`.